# Push notifications not displayed as alert but only displayed in system tray in capacitor

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I have recently migrated my Ionic cordova app to capacitor while doing that I have migrated from `cordova-plugin-firebasex` to `@capacitor/push-notifications`
I see difference in displaying of notifications in capacitor than cordova.

**Any insights on how can we display notification alert instead of only in system tray similar to cordova firebasex?**

[In `cordova-plugin-firebasex`,](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#cloud-messaging)

[image: In cordova-plugin-firebasex]

In [@capacitor/push-notifications](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications) (internally [FCM](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications))

[image: fcm]